# Why IntelliJ IDEA doesn't show actuator Beans and Mappings after running application?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot-actuator

IDEA version: 2022.2.5.
I can't see any information in Run -> Actuator tab (except Health).
I am getting notifications after launching my Spring Boot 3 app:

```
Failed to retrieve 'mappings' endpoint data
Failed to retrieve application beans snapshot: :application=*
```

I am creating new app, in another existing app everything is fine. But my new app uses `spring-boot-devtools` dependency, maybe it is the reason. Although I removed this dependency, the problem remained.

I opened actuator endpoints:
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: info, ...`.
I used option
`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` but no result.

What can be the reason, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please enable the 'Enable debug output' checkbox for your Spring Boot run configuration in order to observe the Auto-configuration report provided by Spring Boot in the Console tab. It should help to ensure that endpoint beans were not initialized and why. If you can't find the issue, please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new and share any sample project to reproduce this problem.